# Django SQL AJAX Call Not Responding

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have the following javascript script attached to a Create modal, in which I am trying to create a new entry into my SQLite3 table.

I've adjusted the submit button type to = button rather than submit but now the button will not even click (the modal does nothing and does not go away/reset). If I update it to submit, the modal will act like it's working but then not create the entry.

Any ideas what would be causing this?

stakeholders.html

```
........

<!--New Modal-->
<div class="modal fade" id="new" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">New Item</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="addUser" action="">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="employee" placeholder="employee" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="description" placeholder="description" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="stakeholder_group" placeholder="stakeholder_group" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="stakeholder_quadrant" placeholder="stakeholder_quadrant" required>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary form-control" type="button">SUBMIT</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

........

$('form#addUser').on('click','[type=button]', function(e){ 

console.log("ing")
 e.preventDefault();
    var employeeInput = $('input[name="employee"]').val().trim();
    var descriptionInput = $('input[name="description"]').val().trim();
    var stakeholder_groupInput = $('input[name="stakeholder_group"]').val().trim();
    var stakeholder_quadrantInput = $('input[name="stakeholder_quadrant"]').val().trim();
    if (employeeInput && descriptionInput && stakeholder_groupInput && stakeholder_quadrantInput) {
        // Create Ajax Call
        $.ajax({
            url: '{% url 'polls:crud_ajax_create' %}',
            data :  {
                'employee': employeeInput,
                'description': descriptionInput,
                'stakeholder_group': stakeholder_groupInput,
                'stakeholder_quadrant': stakeholder_quadrantInput
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.user) {
                  appendToUsrTable(data.user);
                }
            }
        });
    alert(stakeholder_groupInput +","+stakeholder_quadrantInput)
    } else {
        alert(stakeholder_groupInput +","+stakeholder_quadrantInput)
        alert("All fields must have a valid value.");
    }
    $('form#addUser').trigger("reset");
    return false;
})
```